# Set all checkboxes to checked as default with Checklist-model

Tags: angularjs, checklist-model

I am using [Checklist-model](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) to display some data with checkboxes. The data is provided as the result of a promise.  The list is populating but I want to set all of the checkboxes to checked as default.  How can I accomplish this?

Here is my code:

```js
datas.getRules().then(
  function (resRules) 
  {
    $scope.rules = resRules.data._embedded.rules;
    $scope.versionForm.ignoreRule = $scope.rules.map(r => r.id);

    console.log($scope.versionForm.ignoreRule);
  },
  function (resRulesErr) 
  {
     console.log(resRulesErr);
  }
);
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Include</th>
      <th>Rule</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="r in rules track by $index">
      <td><input type="checkbox" checklist-model="versionForm.ignoreRule" checklist-value="r.id" />
      </td>
      <td>{{r.expression}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When `$scope.versionForm.ignoreRule` prints to console, it shows [64, 67, 18].

Comment: where does `checklist-model` directive come from? Angular core has no such directive

Comment: https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model

Answer (score 0):

Few issues with your code:

```
$scope.versionForm.ignoreRule = $scope.rules.map(r => r.id);
```

it should be

```
$scope.versionForm.ignoreRule = $scope.rules;
```

You want to use an array of rules(objects) but you actually have in there an array of ids.

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in rules track by $index">
```

it should be

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in rules track by r.id">
```

and you have to ensure that the id is unique.